# MYSQL select where column like column1%column2

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 3 fields, name, firstname and lastname

I want to see how many rows in the table have name of the form firstname%lastname

I tried to do

```
 select * from family_watchdog_offender where name like firstname%lastname\G
```

but that returned a syntax error regarding the %lastname portion of the query.  Is there some syntax that will allow me to run a query such as this?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean by firstname%lastname\G. If you want to use the like expression, it should start with %some_criteria%, and always put all the values you are either selecting or evaluating in mysql query in a single quote. e.g '%firstnamelastname%'

Comment: @Chibuzo - a 'like' expression can use `%` anywhere in it, so `like 'firstname%lastname'` is valid. Sean is trying to use the column values, without using the quotes. See Shef's answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM family_watchdog_offender WHERE name  LIKE CONCAT(firstname, '%', lastname);
```

Comment: +1 @Shref you are of course correct. I swear I saw MSSQL. D'oh

Comment: Worked as desired. Thanks greatly for your help

Answer (score 2):

Try concat-ing the `%`:

```
select * from family_watchdog_offender where name like CONCAT(firstname, '%', lastname)
```

Comment: `+` doesn't concatenate strings in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that...This may be what you need to do

```
SELECT * 
FROM family_watchdog_offender 
WHERE name  LIKE CONCAT(firstname, '%') 
 AND name LIKE CONCAT('%', lastname);
```